# How to show Confirm Dialog under Vista with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-vista

I need to set a register key in vista but if I use the commands without running as Administrator it throws an exception. How do I show the confirmation dialog, then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed a manifest with correct user level
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/cb8af5c1-8b06-4d14-a1f3-ed0203354e0c

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run your application with admin rights.
Try "Run As User" to do this.

Comment: Well, I don't wan't to tell all my users "You have to run as administrator this program..."

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user has the needed rights before setting the registry key
[start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ba4k1c5(VS.71).aspx)